# How to set Typescript target lib?

Tags: typescript, clearscript

Hi I'm using the clearscript V8 engine and want to enable TypeScript.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023498/loading-the-typescript-compiler-into-clearscript-wscript-is-undefined-imposs/19788660) post I'm able to load the https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/typescriptServices.js javascript code into V8 and use that to transpile typescript code, but is seems to use an old version ES3 as a default target for the transpiled js.

How can I set the transpilation target to ES2021? All guidance is about [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) used with tsc.exe but I can't seem to figure out how to do this when using typescript.js straight in V8.

Comment: For anyone who comes after, [here] (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-Api) is some guidance from ms on how to use the ts api, the first example shows how to set the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transpile` function actually looks like this:

```
function transpile(input, compilerOptions, fileName, diagnostics, moduleName) { ... }
```

My guess is that `compilerOptions` is expected to be a JavaScript object that complies with the [TSConfig `compilerOptions` reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions).

UPDATE: Try something like `ts.transpile(code, { target: 'es2021' })`.

Comment: will check asap, that seems promising indeed.

Comment: Also found this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-Api from Microsoft, first example shows  (at least one way) how to set the target.